# does scale matter when baking normals and sculpting?

Tags: sculpting, baking, normal-map

Is it better to make a mesh bigger than usual, than scale them down to correct proportion after sculpting/baking is done? I feel like the brushes have a hard time doing what I want them to do when working on smaller scale game props (i.e 2x4 planks of wood). This also brought up another question about baking, does the scale matter when baking normals? Would i get more accurate results? What is the standard practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, scale shouldn't affect a bake or a sculpt (other than that you need a bigger brush for sculpting.)  If you find that a bake varies by more than 1/255 in a channel, then it's worth making a bug report.  Variation of 1/255 is possible just from floating point precision errors and not worth reporting.

There are a few corner cases where scale matters, both for sculpting and for baking.  Some sculpting tools can have settings that can be affected by actual world space-- for example, gravity for a cloth brush depends on the size of an object; tiling options are affected by size, etc.  Some materials are affected by size, measured either in local or world space: bump, displacement, subsurface scattering all have values like that (not to mention, using non-UV texture coordinates, like position or object coordinates.)  If the material changes, then the bake changes.

There are also outside corner cases where precision issues may affect objects differently because of their distance from the world origin.  There are issues with this with regular renders, and although I haven't tested, it's reasonable to assume that they would apply just as much to a bake.

Generally speaking, these aren't issues that should affect very many bakes or sculpts, and when they do, it ought to be pretty obvious.  However, the number of potential exceptions makes it difficult to answer a question like this in the abstract.  It is not just brush settings and material nodes that matter; there is also the question of whether or not you have applied scale.